# Showing current music playing information in android

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, audio-player, android-music-player

Is it possible to track registered users of my android app and get information about what music is playing in their music player? If it can be tracked then is it legal to display the music listening information (just track ID, artist name, listening time) in their profile? The user's permission will be given ofcourse.

Basically, I am trying to build an app where registered users can see what other users are playing on their device music player.

Answer (score 1):

If your app can play music, then you can definitely get the details you want, and so long as you have asked for permission from the user i.e in the 'Terms Of Use', you can legally publish that data. If your app is not playing the music, android security policy does not allow one app to view the data of another. In this case your app has no way of knowing which app is currently playing the music, and thus no way of getting the data you require. If on the other hand, you intend for the app to be run on rooted devices, then you can pretty much do anything you want...